# Create Total via calculated fields

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have several calculated controls within a report in Access 2007.
I need to create a running total post calculation of the entire report. What is the best way to do this? Simply using `Sum([field1]+[field2]+[the other 20 fields])` does not work. I get an error. Running sum all is enabled as well.
 How can I correctly display the total after calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Does `sum(iif[field1] is null,0,[field1]))+sum(iif[field1] is null,0,[field1]))+[...field22]` work?

Maybe even `sum[field1] + sum[field2]+...` would work...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to add multiple fields in the detail section, is to set the source of another textbox to =nz(field1, 0) + nz(field2, 0) + nz(field3, 0)... If you want running sum, set the running sum property. If in a group section, then =sum(nz(field1, 0) + nz(field2, 0) + nz(field3, 0)...). Here, the running sum would most likely result in incorrect results.

Comment: What is NZ? and the values after field?

Comment: Nz is a built-in Access/Jet/Ace function to handle nulls. Look in help of https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c